# Vim Python-Mode Folding

Tags: vim, python-mode

I  recently downloaded [Python-Mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode).  When I open a python script, my functions are folded.  I can unfold easily (it's one of the movement keys when you're on top the function definition).  However, I can't figure out how to re-fold the function.

Moreover, and perhaps most importantly, `:help pymode` returns an error ('E149: Sorry, no help for pymode').  So I can't even look up the documentation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 36):

Here a list of folding commands:

```
zf#j creates a fold from the cursor down # lines.
zf/string creates a fold from the cursor to string .
zj moves the cursor to the next fold.
zk moves the cursor to the previous fold.
zo opens a fold at the cursor.
zO opens all folds at the cursor.
zc close a fold at the cursor.
zm increases the foldlevel by one.
zM closes all open folds.
zr decreases the foldlevel by one.
zR decreases the foldlevel to zero -- all folds will be open.
zd deletes the fold at the cursor.
zE deletes all folds.
[z move to start of open fold.
]z move to end of open fold.
```

What you are looking for is `zc`.

Answer (score 5):

You close a fold in vim by pressing `zc`. To close all folds: `zM`. This is all in the Vim docs.

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking in the wrong place then. zc and zo.

Answer (score 3):

Haivng `set foldclose=all` in your `vimrc` will solve it. More details at [`:h fcl`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'foldclose').

This automatically folds when the cursor is not in the fold. Hence, advantageous by not requiring refold by manual typing of commands like `zc`.

You can find list of fold related commands at `help fold-commands`, if you don't want `foldclose` option

Comment: It may also be useful to know that `set nofoldenable` makes sure that when opening, files are "normal", i.e. not folded.